# Switch CSS styles of two elements with link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, styles, switch-statement

I have two tab buttons at the top of this webpage I'm in the middle of building.  There are two styles associated with the buttons a dark blue representing unselected, and light blue mean already selected and view able on the page.  The problem I'm having is that I searched through SO for a simple easy JS function that would switch the CSS styles and the one I have currently does a good job.  The problem I'm having and you'll see this when you look at the page is that both start up with the dark blue background and I only want one of the links called "Overview" to begin with the light blue BG and the "Features" link to have the dark blue BG. When clicked both will switch with the page content.

[web link to page](http://thoughttechnology.com/sciencedivision/latest/pages/products/myoscan.html)

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
        var links = $('.scrollerbtn li a.slt').click(function() {
        links.removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="scrollernav">
        <ul class="scrollerbtn">                
               <li><a class="slt" href="#" id="scroll5load" onclick="changeClass1()">Overview</a></li>
               <li><a class="slt" href="#" id="scroll5load2" onclick="changeClass()">Features</a></li>
        </ul>                
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.scrollerbtn li a.slt {
display: inline;
color: #FFF;
text-align: center;
background-image: url(../../../images/tabbtnselect.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center 5px;
width: 130px;
height: 40px;
line-height: 50px;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: normal;
text-decoration: none;
margin-right: 10px;
float: left;
margin-left: -30px;
}


.scrollerbtn li a.slt.active {
display: inline;
color: #333;
text-align: center;
background-image: url(../../../images/tabbtn.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center 5px;
width: 130px;
height: 40px;
line-height: 50px;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: normal;
text-decoration: none;
margin-right: 10px;
float: left;
margin-left: -30px;
}
```

How would I go about modifying this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically you need to do is change the active tab background image by clicking it right...?

Comment: you can use jQuery tabs to be give a great look to your site. http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Answer (score 1):

Add the active class to the 'Overview' tab.

```
<ul class="scrollerbtn">                
    <li><a class="slt active" href="#" id="scroll5load" onclick="changeClass1()">Overview</a></li>
    <li><a class="slt" href="#" id="scroll5load2" onclick="changeClass()">Features</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you can also remove the onclick attributes altogether since you are using the more elegant JQuery solution.